# Update in Laravel + Vue CRUD has strange behavior when image is present in data payload

Tags: laravel, vuejs3, inertiajs

I'm facing a weird situation with a CRUD made using Laravel 9 + Vue3 + Inertia 0.69

I have a simple form to update a record with 3 fields: Name, Category and Photo, and it is a copy of create form which is working fine.

So my controller `create` and `update` function are

```
public function store(PatternFormRequest $request)
    {
        $pattern = Pattern::create($request->validated());

        if ($request->file('photo')) {
            $photo = MediaUploader::fromSource($request->file('photo'))
                ->toDirectory('patterns')
                ->upload();
            CreateImageVariants::dispatch($photo, ['thumb', 'webp']);
            $pattern->attachMedia($photo, 'photo');
        }
        $request->session()->flash('success', 'Pattern ' . $pattern->name . ' created!');

        return redirect()->route('admin.pattern.index');
    }


   public function update(PatternFormRequest $request, Pattern $pattern)
    {

        $pattern->update($request->validated());

        if ($request->file('photo')) {
            $photo = MediaUploader::fromSource($request->file('photo'))
                ->toDirectory('patterns')
                ->upload();
            CreateImageVariants::dispatch($photo, ['thumb', 'webp']);
            $pattern->attachMedia($photo, 'photo');
        }
        $request->session()->flash('success', 'Pattern ' . $pattern->name . ' updated!');

        return redirect()->route('admin.pattern.index');
    }
```

Now, the form request class for validation is:

```
<?php

...
class PatternFormRequest extends FormRequest
{
    ...
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:191'],
            'category_id' => ['required', 'numeric', 'min:1'],
            'photo' => ['nullable', 'image'],
        ];
    }
    ...
}
```

At this point, creation process works as expected, but update process is showing abnormal behavior.

**case 1: update data but no image**
record is updated succesfully

**case 2: update only image (which must send original data to the backend)**
data is not reaching controller and FormRequest fires required fields errors

Payload for put request shows that data is sent

```
-----------------------------25814372903303963508392378651
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="name"

AN-018
-----------------------------25814372903303963508392378651
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="category_id"

7
-----------------------------25814372903303963508392378651
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="photo"; filename="pattern.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg
```

Setting required fields as `nullable` and dumping `$request->validated()` or `$request->all()` in update function for case 2, is `[]` an empty array.

In addition, dumping `$pattern` shows the entire model

```
App\Models\Pattern {#1513 ▼ // app/Http/Controllers/Admin/PatternController.php:101
  #connection: "mysql"
  #table: "patterns"
  #primaryKey: "id"
  #keyType: "int"
  +incrementing: true
  #with: []
  #withCount: []
  +preventsLazyLoading: false
  #perPage: 15
  +exists: true
  +wasRecentlyCreated: false
  #escapeWhenCastingToString: false
  #attributes: array:6 [▼
    "id" => 112
    "name" => "AN-018"
    "category_id" => 7
    "deleted_at" => null
    "created_at" => "2023-05-03 20:41:48"
    "updated_at" => "2023-05-03 20:41:48"
  ]
  #original: array:6 [▼
    "id" => 112
    "name" => "AN-018"
    "category_id" => 7
    "deleted_at" => null
    "created_at" => "2023-05-03 20:41:48"
    "updated_at" => "2023-05-03 20:41:48"
  ]
  #changes: []
  #casts: array:3 [▼
    "id" => "integer"
    "category_id" => "integer"
    "deleted_at" => "datetime"
  ]
  #classCastCache: []
  #attributeCastCache: []
  #dates: []
  #dateFormat: null
  #appends: []
  #dispatchesEvents: []
  #observables: []
  #relations: []
  #touches: []
  +timestamps: true
  #hidden: []
  #visible: []
  #fillable: array:3 [▶]
  #guarded: array:1 [▶]
  #forceDeleting: false
  -mediaDirtyTags: []
}


So I'm pulling my hair out, figuratively, of course, because I'm bald.
```